# Не собирается драйвер QIBASE linux

Tags: qt, qmake

Я пытаюсь собрать драйвер QIBASE для работы с qtcreator в Ubuntu Linux.
Согласно [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qibase-plugin-on-unix-and-macos), необходимо переключиться в каталог, куда будет собран драйвер, и через qmake собрать его.
При попытке выполнить ряд комманд козлится, что делать без понятия.
qt версии Qt Creator 6.0.2, основан на Qt 5.15.3. Firebird 5.0 и библиотека libtommath-dev.

```
nikit@nikit-Linux:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers$ qmake -- IBASE_PREFIX=/opt/firebird IBASE_LIBS=-lfbclient
Usage: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project

Mode:
  -project       Put qmake into project file generation mode
                 In this mode qmake interprets [files] as files to
                 be added to the .pro file. By default, all files with
                 known source extensions are added.
                 Note: The created .pro file probably will 
                 need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
                 specify what modules are required.
  -makefile      Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as project files to
                 be processed, if skipped qmake will try to find a project
                 file in your current working directory

Warnings Options:
  -Wnone         Turn off all warnings; specific ones may be re-enabled by
                 later -W options
  -Wall          Turn on all warnings
  -Wparser       Turn on parser warnings
  -Wlogic        Turn on logic warnings (on by default)
  -Wdeprecated   Turn on deprecation warnings (on by default)

Options:
   * You can place any variable assignment in options and it will be *
   * processed as if it was in [files]. These assignments will be    *
   * processed before [files] by default.                            *
  -o file        Write output to file
  -d             Increase debug level
  -t templ       Overrides TEMPLATE as templ
  -tp prefix     Overrides TEMPLATE so that prefix is prefixed into the value
  -help          This help
  -v             Version information
  -early         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before default_pre.prf
  -before        All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before [files] (the default)
  -after         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed after [files]
  -late          All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right after default_post.prf
  -norecursive   Don't do a recursive search
  -recursive     Do a recursive search
  -set <prop> <value> Set persistent property
  -unset <prop>  Unset persistent property
  -query <prop>  Query persistent property. Show all if <prop> is empty.
  -qtconf file   Use file instead of looking for qt.conf
  -cache file    Use file as cache           [makefile mode only]
  -spec spec     Use spec as QMAKESPEC       [makefile mode only]
  -nocache       Don't use a cache file      [makefile mode only]
  -nodepend      Don't generate dependencies [makefile mode only]
  -nomoc         Don't generate moc targets  [makefile mode only]
  -nopwd         Don't look for files in pwd [project mode only]
nikit@nikit-Linux:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers$ ls
libqsqlite.so  libqsqlpsql.so
nikit@nikit-Linux:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers$
```

Comment: укажите .pro для qmake. и вообще, нафига его собирать? просто из репы поставить драйвер вера не позволяет?